# \1 not defined in the RE

Tags: regex, bash, sed

In my script, I'm in passing a markdown file and using sed, I'm trying to find lines that do not have one or more # and are not empty lines and then surround those lines with `<p></p>` tags

**My reasoning:**

`^[^#]+` At beginning of line, find lines that do not begin with 1 or more #

`.\+` Then find lines that contain one or more character (aka not empty lines)

Then replace the matched line with `<p>\1</p>`, where `\1` represents the matched line.

However, I'm getting "\1 not defined in the RE". Is my reasoning above correct and how do I fix this error?

```
BODY=$(sed -E 's/^[^#]+.\+/<p>\1</p>/g' "$1")
```

Comment: `\1` refers to the first match inside a pair of parentheses, e.g., `(.)`.  You don't have any such expression.

Comment: If you want to substitute the whole match, use `&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslash followed by a number is replaced with the match for the Nth capture group in the regexp, but your regexp has no capture groups.

If you want to replace the entire match, use `&`:

```
BODY=$(sed -E 's%^[^#].*%<p>&</p>%' "$1")
```

You don't need to use `.+` to find non-empty lines -- the fact that it has a character at the beginning that doesn't match `#` means it's not empty. And you don't need `+` after `[^#]` -- all you care is that the first character isn't `#`. You also don't need the `g` modifier when the regexp matches the entire line -- that's only needed to replace multiple matches per line.

And since your replacement string contains `/`, you need to either escape it or change the delimiter to some other character.

Comment: Okay I tried that but I got `bad flag in substitute command: '>`

Comment: nvm figured it out i changed the deliminator to `BODY=$(sed -E 's%^[^#].*%<p>&</p>%g' "$1")`

Comment: You don't need the `g` modifier, since it can only match once per line.

Comment: The delimiter problem is a different issue than the one you originally mentioned.